# how to install python-rest-client lib in linux

Tags: python, json, rest

I need to use python-rest-client package into my project. I tried several times for installing python-rest-client into my linux python, it never worked. But it works well in Windows python. Would anybody tell me how to install python-rest-client in linux python.

Comment: What doesn't work ? Your installation of the package, or using the package under Linux ? For either case, can you post examples or tracebacks of your issues ?

Comment: `easy_install python-rest-client` or `pip install python-rest-client`

Comment: I can get, I can post. it works well in my Windows Eclipse environment. But I don't know how to config an environment in Linux. I mean I've got Python2.7 installed in Linux then how do I do to install python-rest-client package?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer would you please give me a specific explanation on that? I'm really a new comer for this Linux world. :-) Thanks in advance.

Comment: From now on I still couldn't figure this out, is there anyone would give me a hand?

Comment: Please, I'm actually looking for the answer. Somebody help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avasal, you were right. I did it by  `pip install python-rest-client`